# "El cactus más alto en el horizonte" Omegaup

Tags: c, ordenamiento

Alguien me podría ayudar a optimizar mi código ya que tarda demasiado y he hecho varios intentos y no logro resolverlo.
Aqui el link del problema
https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/cactus_horizonte/#problems

Lo que hice fue ordenar el arreglo de forma descendente y después ir comparando con el otro arreglo tal como lo pide el problema pero siempre logro que me de 95 puntos ya que tarda demasiado
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO8uW.jpg

Aqui mi código

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <algorithm>
 void Vec_Ordenado(int vec[], int, 
 int ord[]);
 int main()
 {
    int Alturas, Preguntas;
    scanf("%d", &Alturas);
    int vec[Alturas];
    int ord[Alturas];
    for (int i = 0; i < Alturas; i++)
    {
       scanf("%d", &vec[i]);
    }
    Vec_Ordenado(vec, Alturas, ord);
    scanf("%d", &Preguntas);
    int arr[Preguntas];
    for (int i = 1; i <= Preguntas; i++)
    {
       scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= Preguntas; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 1; j <= Alturas; j++)
       {
           if (arr[i] == j)
           {
              printf("%d ", ord[j]);
           }
       }
     }

return 0;
```

}

Y ésto es la parte de la función

```
void Vec_Ordenado(int vec[], int 
Alturas, int ord[])
{
    std::sort(vec, vec + Alturas);
    int z = 1;
    for (int i = Alturas - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
       ord[z++] = vec[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: No se el resto del algoritmo.. pero esto: for (int i = 1; i <= Preguntas; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 1; j <= Alturas; j++)
       {
           if (arr[i] == j)
           {
              printf("%d ", ord[j]);
           }
       }
     } no tiene mucho sentido.. si solo agarras la diagonal menor, directamente hace un solo for...

Comment: Si lo tomé en cuenta de hecho lo simplifique a un solo for como tú dices pero aún asi me da la misma puntuación.